# BatchApex - System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out

Tags: apex, batch

I am making a callout and then trying to insert the data and then immediately I make another callout followed by insert operation.  This process continues for users matching my criteria.  How to avoid below exception?

I know that its not allowed to do a callout and a DML in series.  But as per the requirement I need to follow this process.

System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out

Note: I cannot use future method since I am running this process in a batch class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Batch Size of 1

```
Database.executeBatch(myClass, 1);
```

This will let you perform a callout per record. It'll be kind of slow though (~3 seconds per record).

## Callout First

Perform all callouts (up to 100) *first*, then perform one batch update. You'll want to do this anyways to avoid other governor limits like query limits, dml limits, or timeout limits.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it works as expected.  I have another question, what if there are 10000 batches, will this work or will it require something else?

Comment: @SriramLns Sure, you can have up to 250,000 calls *per day* (shared between future methods, batches, and queuable). You'll have a decently hard time trying to reach that limit.

Answer (score 0):

The better design would be to do the following:

1. Loop through qualified users, making a callout for each one
2. Create records with response from callout.
3. update create records

   ```
   List<MyRecord__c> toInsert = new List<MyRecord__c>();
   for(User u : users){
      String resp = makeCallout(u);
      MyRecord__c myRecord = createRecordFromResponse(resp);
      toInsert.add(myRecord);
   }
   insert toInsert;
   ```

I believe you can have up to 100 callouts in a single execution context so you'll want to execute the batch class like so: `Database.executeBatch(myClass, 100);`

It would be even better if the webservice was bulkified but with third party systems, this often isn't an option.

Comment: your solution also makes sense but only thing that I am worried is that what if after 100 batches I get any exception like Apex CPU time limit exceeded.  What will happen to the un-inserted records?