# Batch callout error: Call out made it firstbefore DML

Tags: unit-test, batch, failing-tests, calloutexception

I have review similar questions, and all of them mention to do API before any DML

[similar question 1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/159836/batch-notexecuted-you-have-uncommitted-work-pending-please-commit-or-rollback) and
[similar question 2](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/80476/batchapex-system-calloutexception-you-have-uncommitted-work-pending-please-c)

However, I am trying to do the API in the excecute, and I am still getting **You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out** but i dont understand why I am getting this, there is no DML aside from Database.QueryLocator in the start, but based on those answer I understood this was still ok to do.

When I run this in the sandbox (no via test method) the batch works correctly.

My class:

```
// Database.executeBatch(new BatchMinIT5009(), 50);
global class BatchMinIT5009 implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts, Database.Stateful {
    global Integer recordsProcessed = 0;
    global Boolean isSandbox;

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {         
        return Database.getQueryLocator(
            'SELECT Id, Loan_Number__c FROM Opportunity WHERE (StageName = \'Loan Funded\')'
        );
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Opportunity> scope){

        Set<String> scope_JSON = new Set<String>();
        Set<String> oppLoanNumberSet = new Set<String>();
        Map<String, Opportunity> oppLoanNumberMap = new Map<String, Opportunity>();

        for (Opportunity o:scope) {
            recordsProcessed++;
            scope_JSON.add(o.Id);
            oppLoanNumberSet.add(o.Loan_Number__c);
            oppLoanNumberMap.put(o.Loan_Number__c, o);            
        }

        //MY CALL OUT
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        req.setTimeout(120000);
        req.setEndpoint('https://eng963ivpdn16.x.pipedream.net/');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
        res = http.send(req);
        String api_res_body = res.getBody();        
        System.debug('%%% api res \n' + api_res_body); 

    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        isSandbox = HelperClass.runningInASandbox();
        AsyncApexJob job = [SELECT Id, Status, NumberOfErrors, 
        JobItemsProcessed,
        TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email
        FROM AsyncApexJob
        WHERE Id = :bc.getJobId()];

        String emailBody              = JSON.serialize(job);
        String emailTo                = 'email@email.com';
        String emailSenderDisplayName = 'Saving loans schedules - Original (5009)';
        String emailSubject           = 'Something was wrong, is sandbox: ' + String.valueOf(isSandbox);
        String emailReplyTo           = 'email@email.com';
        if (job.NumberOfErrors > 0) {
            String emailResponse          = HelperClass.emailMethod(emailTo,emailBody,emailSenderDisplayName,emailSubject,emailReplyTo);
        }
    }    
}
```

My test class:

```
static testMethod void test_MinIT5009() {

    Map<String, String> responseHeaders = new Map<String, String>();
    responseHeaders.put('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    Test.startTest();
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new Test_HttpCalloutMock(200, 'OK', 'OK:^2020-03-04~200~275189|2020-04-04~200~275190|2020-05-04~200~275191',responseHeaders));
        Database.executeBatch(new BatchMinIT5009(), 50);
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How are you creating the test Opportunity data... in a `@testSetup` method?

I've seen some glitchy behaviour resulting from certain combinations of unit tests + callouts + asynchronous Apex + `Test.startTest()`/`Test.stopTest()` + `Test.setMock` + workflow emails or Apex emails. Something confusing happens, in which the behaviour of collapsing async work into one unit test transaction causes a spurious "You have uncommitted work pending" error.

I'm not sure the implementation of your `HelperClass.emailMethod` but maybe that's similar to what's happening here.

Sometimes to get proper coverage on a Batchable I simply have to test each of its individual methods alone. That might be another way to go.

Comment: Yes my data is created on @testSetup, even if i dont run HelperClass.emailMethod, I still get the same error, the only time i dont get the error is if I do an API in the start method (before the return) or in the constructor of the class (currently not present), but i did this to test as i need each record been process in the excecution to do the API

Comment: The fact that it even fails if you don't run the `emailMethod`... now that's a stumper. Maybe turn on the finest possible debug log, capture that from the unit test run, and look for any signs of anything it might count as DML.

Comment: Also is it possible that your `@testSetup` data creation triggers any workflows/processes that send Email Alerts? That could be a factor in the glitch.